# Class 'Psr\Log\NullLogger' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\evernote\evernote-cloud-sdk-php\src\Evernote\Client.php on line 156

Tags: php, evernote

When creating a Client in Evernote sandbox sample:

```
$client = new \Evernote\Client($token, $sandbox);
```

I'm getting following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Psr\Log\NullLogger' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\evernote\evernote-cloud-sdk-php\src\Evernote\Client.php on line 156

I know, this is because of missing: **Psr\Log**, files but I do not know where I should add them?

I don't want to use composer because I'm not sure if I will be able to use it in production. Anyway the settings is as follows: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/blob/master/composer.json

Does anyone know how to add the Psr\Log into Evernote PHP SDK API please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After some testing I found the solution as follows:

1. download ZIP file of: **Psr\Log**, from: https://github.com/php-fig/log
2. save folder: **Psr**, into folder: *evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src*
3. change file: **autoload.php**, within folder: *evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src*, as follows:

Add new value into array:

```
$namespaces = array( 
     'EDAM',
     'Thrift',
     'Evernote',
     'Psr'
);
```

Create new function:

```
function psrAutoload($className, $lastNsPos)
{
    return genericAutoload($className, $lastNsPos);
}
```

Seems to be working so far, hope it will help someone to safe time.